# writing object to file using gson is blocking UI thread and taking all RAM

Tags: java, android, json

I am trying to write an object of a class to a file and them read it back using toJson and fromJson. It was working with my test class, but now, it takes all ram that is available and does it until android kills a process.
This is what`s going on in my logcat
[image]

Here is my writeObject method. It stops when executing second line in the code(marked in a comment line)

```
 public void writeObject(coin coinObj) {
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    Log.d("writeObject","Created Gson object");
    String s = gson.toJson(coinObj); //----THIS LINE CAUSE A TROUBLE
    Log.d("writeObject","line 2");
    FileOutputStream outputStream;
    Log.d("writeObject","line 3");
    try {
        outputStream = openFileOutput("file1.txt", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        outputStream.write(s.getBytes());
        outputStream.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.d("catch","Exception e");
    }
}
```

My onCreat method

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    coockie = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.cookieId);
    coinNumberView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.coockieNumberId);
    buyListNav = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.buyListNav);
  final coin  coin1;
    coin1 =new coin(0, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,0,5,10,20,40,80,160,320,720,1440,2880);
    Log.d("onCreate coin",coin1.getIncome()+"");
    Log.d("onCreate","User has been initialized");
    coin1.writeObject(coin1);
```

This is the code of my coin class. There are setters and getters, but there is no point in adding them.(I know I should have gone for arrays but I just want to make it work like that)

```
public class coin extends AppCompatActivity {
private volatile long coinsNumber=0;
private volatile long income;
private volatile long coinsPerClick;
private volatile int packOfCiggarreteNumber;
private volatile int item2Number;
private volatile int item3Number;
private volatile int item4Number;
private volatile int item5Number;
private volatile int item6Number;
private volatile int item7Number;
private volatile int item8Number;
private volatile int item9Number;
private volatile int item10Number;
private volatile int packOfCiggarretePrice;
private volatile int item2Price;
private volatile int item3Price;
private volatile int item4Price;
private volatile int item5Price;
private volatile int item6Price;
private volatile int item7Price;
private volatile int item8Price;
private volatile int item9Price;
private volatile int item10Price;
public coin (long coinsNumber1, long income1,long coinsPerClick1,int packOfCigarreteNumber1,int item2Number1,
               int item3Number1,int item4Number1,int item5Number1,int item6Number1,int item7Number1,int item8Number1,
               int item9Number1,int item10Number1,int packOfCiggarretePrice1,int item2Price1,int item3Price1,
             int item4Price1,int item5Price1,int item6Price1,int item7Price1,int item8Price1,int item9Price1,int item10Price1)
{
    coinsNumber = coinsNumber1;
    income=income1;
    coinsPerClick=coinsPerClick1;
    packOfCiggarreteNumber=packOfCigarreteNumber1;
    item2Number=item2Number1;
    item3Number=item3Number1;
    item4Number=item4Number1;
    item5Number=item5Number1;
    item6Number=item6Number1;
    item7Number=item7Number1;
    item8Number=item8Number1;
    item9Number=item9Number1;
    item10Number=item10Number1;
    packOfCiggarretePrice=packOfCiggarretePrice1;
    item2Price=item2Price1;
    item3Price=item3Price1;
    item4Price=item4Price1;
    item5Price=item5Price1;
    item6Price=item6Price1;
    item7Price=item7Price1;
    item8Price=item8Price1;
    item9Price=item9Price1;
    item10Price=item10Price1;
}
```

Comment: Why does your class extends AppCompatActivity ??

Comment: I am using Toast in some of methods

Comment: So? Coin is obviously not an activity. Dont extend an activity. Whatever youd do would nit work or produce undesired result or worse would appear to work but still do something wrong. Find another way.

Comment: Like static methods taking an activity as parameter.

Comment: I don't extent activity anymore but the issue is still here

Answer (score 0):

Well basically, what is happening is that you are outputting the JSON in a way that buffers it in memory.  If the data structure you are trying to save is too big, it won't work.

One way to work around this is to write directly to an `Appendable` ... which could be a `Writer`:

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
Writer w = ...
gson.toJson(obj, w);
w.close();
```

Note: the above is NOT production quality code.  It does not deal with exceptions or ensure that the writer is always closed ... to protect against leakage.

---

Having said that, if your data structure is currently large enough that you don't have enough memory to serialize it (using `toString()`), it could soon be too large to hold in memory at all.

And there may be other / better ways to persist the application state than doing JSON serialization.

Comment: It saves one object with 3 long and bunch of int variables. It shouldn't take that much ram. I mean, I tried to launch it on my phone, and it took 528 mb of available ram, not to mention, it also took 40 secs to get that ram afther wich android has killed the process. 
I think problem is with something else, i mean, that`s my guess, I am new to android.

Comment: If you are really just saving 3 longs and a bunch of ints, then it is definitely something else.  Like maybe you are saving a huge list of them.  Or maybe the problem is nothing to do with this code at all.

Comment: It's 3 longs and 21 ints. That's a lot, but not that much to take 528 mb of ram

Comment: That is NOT a lot.  The JSON should be less than 1Kb.  Yes ... kilobytes.  Something else is going on.  Check the logcat output.

Comment: I tested both on my device (Lg g2) and genymotion. Result is white blank screen and crash (OutOfMemory error) in about 30-40 secs

Comment: Yup.  All symptoms of a different problem.